# Issue while executing Shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to automate domain creation process.For that I have wrote required commands in a document and trying to run it from terminal. And facing "echo not found error". Below is my code.Can someone verify and let me know if there is any error or suggest are there any prerequisites to execute shell script.

Note: I am working on UBUNTU 14.04 OS

```html
echo "Enter Site Name(xyz.com):"
read siteName
mkdir $HOME/Desktop/work/$siteName
mkdir $HOME/Desktop/work/$siteName/public_html
chmod 777 -R $HOME/Desktop/work/$siteName

echo "<VirtualHost *:80>" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/$siteName
echo "  ServerName $siteName" >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$siteName
echo "  ServerAlias www.$siteName" >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$siteName
echo "  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/$siteName" >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$siteName
echo "</VirtualHost>" >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/$siteName

cd  /var/www
ln -s   $HOME/Desktop/work/$siteName/public_html  $siteName
a2ensite $siteName
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: You need to specify which shell you're targetting. Also this is not a PHP question.

Comment: Try putting `set -x` at the top of your script and check which line is throwing the error.

Comment: Why is this tagged php?  How are you trying to execute this?  Are you trying `php ./script` ?